# fatal error C1001: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1794)

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-6, internal-compiler-error

I tried to compile a project with Visual Studio 6 SP6 and got the following:

```
usbcore.h(18) : fatal error C1001: INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR
    (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1794)
     Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
     Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Line 18 of usbcore.h contains the include directive:

```
18: #include "usbiface.h"
```

Empty or non-existing usbiface.h produces the same error. I commented this line and got the same error but for the next include file.

**To sum this up:** the compiler error occurs for each `#include` directive that refers to the common project headers.

Comment: I appreciate that you probably struggled for a long time to figure this out.  But if you are going to ask a question for the specific purpose of answering it yourself, I'd like to see quite a bit more detail, especially in the question.  -1 until then.

Comment: Also voting to close on its own merits as being unclear.  As asked, there is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @John Dibling: What details are you missing? I want to share info about the compiler error to save someone's time because I spent a day trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what caused that error. One of the include paths (passed to a compiler with the /I switch) had a trailing backslash.

The compiler cmdline is: `CPP /nologo /MT /W3 /GX /Zi /Od /I "$(ZLIB_PATH)" /I "..\headers"`

and `ZLIB_PATH` had a trailing backshlash. Removing that backslash solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, changing the tag WholeProgramOptimizationtrue from true to false fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when I left the parenthesis off of the definition of a ctor.  It was a stupid error but it was very taxing to check out all of these tough fixes.  So I just offer this as a possibility. I would not have expected an internal compiler error.

Comment: Same here for me, but for the destructor. Don't forget the parenthesis for both of them...

Answer (score 0):

In my case (VC6.0 SP6a), it is due to the confusing `using` statement. It seems the compiler can't determine whether I'm defining `Foo::Bar` or `Bar` (in global namespace).

```
namespace Foo {
    class Bar;
}

using Foo::Bar;

class Bar {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to turn off the "Generate browse info" option to avoid this. (Project settings \ C/C++ \ General)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to migrate a NET4.8 project to NET7. After switching the CLR version in the C++/CLI project I started to see the error:

```
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.12\ref\net7.0\mscorlib.dll : fatal  error C1001: Internal compiler error.
1>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1639)
```

To resolve it, I followed [problems migrating c++/cli project from .net 4.7 to .netcore 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754706/problems-migrating-c-cli-project-from-net-4-7-to-netcore-3-1).

Removing `<CompileAsManaged>true</CompileAsManaged>` from .vcxproj helped resolve the issue.