# problems migrating c++/cli project from .net 4.7 to .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I am migrating a wpf .net 4.7 Solution to .net core 3.1
I'm working with Visual Studio 16.6.3.
the wpf project is compiling fine with .net core.
but a depending c++/cli Project does not compile.
I changed the .vcxproject according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli.
the vcxproject now looks like:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword></Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>XY</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <VCToolsVersion>14.26.28801</VCToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)..\..\build\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)..\..\tmp\$(ProjectName)\</IntDir>
    <EnableManagedIncrementalBuild>true</EnableManagedIncrementalBuild>
    <IncludePath>$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <IgnoreImportLibrary>false</IgnoreImportLibrary>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <!-- <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>    -->
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <OutDir>$(ProjectDir)..\..\build\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(ProjectDir)..\..\tmp\$(ProjectName)\</IntDir>
    <EnableManagedIncrementalBuild>true</EnableManagedIncrementalBuild>
    <IncludePath>$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <IgnoreImportLibrary>false</IgnoreImportLibrary>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;WIN32;%(PreprocessorDefinitions);WS_CPLUSPLUS</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>false</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      </PrecompiledHeaderFile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories></AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <AdditionalUsingDirectories>
      </AdditionalUsingDirectories>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
      <CompileAsManaged>true</CompileAsManaged>
      <CallingConvention>
      </CallingConvention>
      <UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions>
      </UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions>
      <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
      <DiagnosticsFormat>Classic</DiagnosticsFormat>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>DebugFull</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableUAC>false</EnableUAC>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories></AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;gdiplus.lib;d2d1.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies);WebServices.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
      <PreventDllBinding>false</PreventDllBinding>
      <Profile>false</Profile>
      <AdditionalOptions></AdditionalOptions>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
 

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  ...
</Project>
```

According to the above link, the System References should be removed and are loaded automatically by vs due to
`<CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>`

but now previously fine compiled CPP files are not compiling anymore with the following error

> c:\program files\dotnet\packs\microsoft.netcore.app.ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\mscorlib.dll : fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
> (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1533)

even if i add the simplest cpp file and compile it with right click-compile the same error occurs, so it not really depends on the cpp code

When I hover over the first char from CPP files in the editor, it shows
'System' not loaded from default assemblies

the cli project was compiling fine before migrating.

Comment: Did you also add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />` to the project, to be able to use those assemblies?

Comment: @thatguy yes that is added

Comment: Maybe once you need to try delete all item from build’s output directory ,clean solution and rebuild solution

Comment: @Dimple Patel i tried that but no success, just this curious compiler error, even with log detailed

Comment: Did you change every `CLRSupport` to `NetCore`? Also, close VS Instance, try to delete `.vs` hidden folder from the solution folder, `Debug` or `Release`, `x64`.... any output folders from the solution folder, or project folder and then restart VS to test again.

Comment: @perry Quian-MSFT thanks for your answer partly resolved

Comment: What is the next errors or issues, could you please share them with us to help you handle your issue further.

Comment: @perry sorry i was too fast - still same error.I added an essence of vcproject file. the compiler error seems independent of the c++ code

Comment: @Perry Quian-MSFT indeed - that works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> problems migrating c++/cli project from .net 4.7 to .netcore 3.1

I have tested in my side : migrate a net framework clr project into net core clr project by the guidance document without any errors.

So please try the following suggestions:

**Suggestion**

Please check to make sure you use these properties in `xxx.vcxproj` file instead.

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport> //there are four parts that need to be edited.
```

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, output folders like `Debug` or `x64`(both on solution folder and project folder)

**2)** Right-click on the c++ project-->**Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**Optimization**-->set `Optimization` to `Disabled(/Od)`

Changing `Link Time Code Generation` to `/LTCG` by Project **Properties** --> **Linker** --> **Optimization**.

**Besides**, please try to create a new default C++ Clr Net Core project and then test whether it can be built successfully.

And if so, you can try to migrate your old project into the new project.

**In addition**, you can share a minimal, reproducible sample with us so that we can troubleshoot your issue more quickly.

====================

**Update**

The reason is that you have use `CompileAsManaged` xml node in your `xxx.vcxproj` file, and for your net core clr project does not need that node. With it, you lose the assembly reference.

**Actually**, that node conflicts with your project due to some reasons whether its value is `true` or `false`.

**Solution**

Delete this node in `xxx.vcxproj` file.

```
<CompileAsManaged>true</CompileAsManaged>
```

Then you will built your project successfully as I did.

Comment: Ran into the same issue upgrading .net 4.7.1 solution to .net 6.0. CompileAsManaged was the culprit. Thank you very much!